# Applications restored after fresh install?

Tags: macos

I do not understand. I have just performed a clean install of OS X El Capitan, from a USB pendrive, after repartitioning and formatting my drive. Yet, for a reason i do not understand at all, my applications seem to have been restored. Yet, as it seems, none of them are functioning properly.

What happened here? How and why were my applications restored, and where from?

Comment: Did you erase before you reinstalled? If you didn't, then that's why the apps are there

Comment: Of course, yes. I repartitioned the drive. I formatted it. It was a clean install. 100%

Comment: Possibly you logged into Mac App Store with your Apple ID, and had all the apps re-downloaded.

Comment: I opened App Store right after the first boot, to download the El Capitan Updates. I am on a very slow connection. It would have taken a long time to download all these ..

Comment: Did you migrate any files at all from a backup? What apps were reinstalled unexpectedly and on exactly which way do they not function?